# Python - Connecting to JDBC

Tags: python, jdbc, odbc

I found this library, [JayDeBeApi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/) which says it will let me connect to JDBC.

Does anyone know if how reliable it is, or if there's a better way to connect?

If not, I'm having trouble setting up JayDeBeAPI.  The [instructions](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/0.1#usage) say to run some Python code to set up JPype but I'm not clear if I need to do that in the same script before calling the connection code, or is it some kind of server I need to leave running?

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you want to use CPython or Jython. For Jython, I would suggest for less complicated cases to use [more simple tools](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/JythonModules#Can_I_use_the_python_DB_API_from_Jython.3F).