# Python 3 - Connecting with JDBC

Tags: database, jdbc, python-3.x

How do you connect to a database using a JDBC driver from within Python 3?  [JayDeBeApi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/) seems to do the job for Python 2, but at the moment it isn't Python 3-compatible.

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938011/python-connecting-to-jdbc), but I am asking specifically about Python 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I can not delete this answer, I will edit it:

Way back when, I created a Python3-port of JayDeBeApi. But as the other answer points out, the official JayDeBeApi now supports Python3 as well.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29888550/554319, JeyDeBeApi already supports Python 3, so this project is not needed anymore I guess.

Answer (score 13):

Starting from version 0.2 the official [JayDeBeApi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/) now supports Python 3 as well. It is still backwards compatible with Python 2 and Jython.

Comment: This should be the (most up to date) accepted answer.

Comment: I encountered while using jaydebeapi:
database connectivity error, value: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /opt/app/py_env/data_layer3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_jpype.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so already loaded in another classloader

Has anyone faced it?

Answer (score -8):

Probably too late to be useful, but I was able to connect from Python 3.3 to a MySQL db on my Windows machine (!) using PyMySql (see https://code.google.com/p/pymysql/).  Once installed, I used a variation on the code from your reference location here: [Python 3 and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/python-3-and-mysql).  I have a schema called "test" and a table called "users", here was the test code:

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='password', db='mysql')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test.users")
for r in cur:
    print(r)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Doesn't the question specifically ask for a JDBC solution?

Comment: This answer is so far away of the topic